# Hacer que un calendario cambien de dia segun el previo calendario

Tags: html

Una manera simple para cuando seleccione una fecha en mi calendario Fecha, automaticamente se selecione 15 dias mas en mi calendario Vigencia como default ya sea con `JavaScript` o `JQuery`?. El atributo tipo "d" es para validar.

```html
<div class="form-group wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100" style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <span class="label-input100">Fecha</span>
    <input type="date" class="input100" id="txtFecha" tipo="d" placeholder="Fecha" required >
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <span class="label-input100">Vigencia</span>
    <input type="date" class="input100" id="txtVigencia" tipo="d" placeholder="Vigencia" required>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te deje ejemplo con `JQuery` que yo he utilizado:

```js
//obtener fecha
$('#txtFecha')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
//agregar metodo onchange
$('#txtFecha').change(function() {
  //obtener fecha del elemento txtFecha
  var fecha = this.valueAsDate;
  //sumar 15 días a la fecha
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 15);
  //asignar la nueva fecha al elemento txtVigencia
  $('#txtVigencia')[0].valueAsDate = fecha;
});
$('#txtFecha').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100" style="margin-left: 10px;">
 <span class="label-input100">Fecha</span>
 <input type="date" class="input100" id="txtFecha" tipo="d"  placeholder="Fecha" required >
 <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100" style="margin-right: 10px;">
 <span class="label-input100">Vigencia</span>
 <input type="date" class="input100" id="txtVigencia" tipo="d" placeholder="Vigencia"  required>
 <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Buena respuesta. No se si viene al caso, pero tal como lo tienes, el usuario puede cambiar el valor de `txtVigencia`. Para evitarlo usaría el atributo `disabled` en vez de `required`.